# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: is_approved of: com

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I am fetching records from purchase table by userid it was working fine but now want to add one condition that is (is_approved) column value is = 1,i added this condition in that same query it was throughing error

//My DAOHibernate method is below

```
public int getNumOfPurchasesByUserId(Integer userId) {
    System.out.println("########################### Calling getNumOfPurchasesByUserId %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
    String sql = "select count(p) from " + Purchase.class.getName() + " p where p.userid = :userid and p.is_approved=1";

    Session session = null;
    Query q = null;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        q = session.createQuery(sql);
        q.setInteger("userid", userId);


        try {
            count = ((Long)q.uniqueResult()).intValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

//my error is

```
########################### Calling getNumOfPurchasesByUserId      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: is_approved of: com.newscom.model.Purchase [select count(p) from     com.newscom.model.Purchase p where p.userid = :userid and p.is_approved=1]
at     org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:81)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:75)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1465)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:315)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:487)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:611)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:263)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:210)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:117)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:113)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:880)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1330)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4471)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3944)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2047)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1975)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:831)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:617)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:244)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:256)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
at com.newscom.dao.hibernate.PurchaseDAOHibernate.getNumOfPurchasesByUserId(PurchaseDA
```

//In purchase

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Purchase")
@NamedQueries(value = {
@NamedQuery(name = "GetPurchaseByUserID", query = "SELECT p from Purchase p where p.userid = :userid order by p.status, p.purchaseid desc"),



private boolean isApproved;
private Date approvalTime;
private Integer approvedBy;

@Column(name="is_approved")
public boolean getIsApproved() {
    return isApproved;
}
public void setIsApproved(boolean isApproved) {
    this.isApproved = isApproved;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `Purchase`?

Comment: hi  purchase this is the named query..

Comment: Post the whole code of the entity please.

Comment: the column is precent in that entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use property name,  not column name in your query:

```
String sql = "select count(p) from " + Purchase.class.getName() + " p where p.userid = :userid and p.isApproved=1";
```

Hope it helps.